# How can I incorporate this JQuery to my D3 force layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to open a URL on node click in a frame or dialog box but can't figure it out.

[Here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajaisle/0tms5xcv/) I've been playing around with around with and [here is the JQuery dialog box](http://jsfiddle.net/P2Q5U/) I am trying to use on it. Below is the code I used to trigger a URL on click but I want to open the URL in dialog box, not the same window. Thanks!

```
    .append("a")
 .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return "http://www.google.com/" + d.atom }) 
  .call(force.drag);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another event listener to your nodes, you already have two, one for `mouseover` and `mouseout`, now you can add one for click (and pass a property to indicate what URL you want to load).

```
.on("click",function(d) { click(d.atom); });
```

Then all you have to do is set a dialog box div's content however you want:

```
function click(link) {
     $("#dialog").html('<iframe src="http://www.'+link+'.com"></iframe>').dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         modal: true
      });

    $("#dialog").dialog('open');

 }
```

Here is a link to an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pzuyhobc/1/

Comment: This is PERFECT. Thank you so much!